# Is it possible to write a function in AHK?

Tags: function, autohotkey

In Python I can use `def` to define a function. Is it possible in AHK? I tried

```
Gosub, MySub 
return

MySub::
MsgBox, It worked.
return
```

But I got:

```
Line Text: MySub::
Error: Invalid hotkey.
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra ':' in your subroutine definition. try this:

```
Gosub, MySub 
return

MySub:  ;  Note single colon
MsgBox, It worked.
return
```

Double colon "::" means definition of a key; single colon ":" means subroutine

Answer (score 3):

To define a function in AHK, use the following syntax:

```
Add(x, y)
{
    return x + y   ; "Return" expects an expression.
}
```

The above defines a function `Add` which returns the sum of its two arguments.   No "function" or "def" keyword is required.

For more detail, see the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm).